# Iphone Adhoc distirbution profile update

Tags: ios, ad-hoc-distribution

I have an AdHoc profile, now I want to add device for that profile, do I need to update certificate also ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you don't. Just add device to the list, click Edit profile, choose newly added device and click Save. After several seconds your profile will be available for downloading.

Answer (score 2):

No, you just need to add the device to the ad-hoc profile.